# Windows 10 media installer fails to start (case 2)

Tags: windows-10, installation, iso-image, bootable-media

Understood that there's another similar title but not so similar situation therefore i put a case2 in the title.

**Background**
In windows 10, i shrunk my D drive and combine the extra volume into my C drive using a free tool which i found on net. It actually works fine for few days, and one day when i start my PC and it couldn't load into the window and divert to the recovery option page. After trying all the available option given by windwos i finally gave up and did a format using Diskpart command in MSDOS mode. After cleaning up, i boot the USB with windows 10 32 and 64bit(I've tried both)  which created from a media creation tool. However it doesn't even proceed to setup page. It just kept looping looping and looping in the first BIOS start up page. The feeling was when it accessed the USB for awhile and it will restart.

Really do not know what is going on......  hope i could get some light from here

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it just keeps looping, that is an indication that the flash drive is not bootable. Try downloading Windows as an ISO if you have not already.

Download [Rufus bootable USB creator](https://rufus.akeo.ie/). When you run the program, make sure you select fat32 for the most compatibility. Your flash drive cannot be larger than 32G.

If your PC is UEFI, select that as the partition scheme. (If your not sure, post your PC model and I'll find out).  Otherwise, select CSM/Legacy. Select the Windows ISO and click start.

Comment: Hi Randy, thanks for replying. I'm using 32GB removable drive and my PC is ASUS ET2321. Tonight i will try the Rufus bootable creator. And i will update again.

Comment: Still looping. The moment i select the ISO, all settings were auto set and i couldn't choose the FAT32. This time i used 16GB  : (

Comment: That is strange. I have never seen a case where you could not select the file format. You can't switch to fat32 before you select the iso or after?

Comment: Hi randy, it said something like Fat32 will not support my current selected ISO system. However i managed to install everything and now my PC is back to normal after i downloaded the media creation tool from Microsoft. All this while i'm using another media creation tool. Really curious what went wrong. I will investigate it and post it here. Thanks for your advise regarding the looping cause was due to bootable media. I almost dissemble the ALL in one pc to take the HD out HAHA